# Sending the mail via Exchange service

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices

Am trying to send the mail via Exchange server without opening the outlook, I have used the code below.
Am following the below code to send the mail directly from the exchange service, but am receiving the error for the autodiscovery url can someone please help me out here.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data;

namespace Serivcemessgae
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2013_SP1);

            service.Credentials = new WebCredentials("karan.kotabagi@***.com", "***");

            service.TraceEnabled = true;
            service.TraceFlags = TraceFlags.All;

            service.AutodiscoverUrl("karan.kotabagi@***.com", RedirectionUrlValidationCallback);

            EmailMessage email = new EmailMessage(service);

            email.ToRecipients.Add("karan.kotabagi@***.com");

            email.Subject = "HelloWorld";
            email.Body = new MessageBody("This is the first email I've sent by using the EWS Managed API");

            email.Send();
        }

        private static bool RedirectionUrlValidationCallback(string redirectionUrl)
        {
            // The default for the validation callback is to reject the URL.
            bool result = false;

            Uri redirectionUri = new Uri(redirectionUrl);

            // Validate the contents of the redirection URL. In this simple validation
            // callback, the redirection URL is considered valid if it is using HTTPS
            // to encrypt the authentication credentials. 
            if (redirectionUri.Scheme == "https")
            {
                result = true;
            }
            return result;


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should tell us what "the error"'s response status code is.

Comment: This started working when I ran this in my organisation network, but it took around 20 minutes for me to get the mail, can you advise is there a way to    fix this to send the mail in a reduced time.